# Strange behavior when merging data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, match

I just have 2 data frames I want to merge into one, and I always use `merge`, but for some reason it is not working as expected for this case...

These are the 2 `data.frames`:

```
> dfa <- as.data.frame(as.character(LETTERS[3:14]))
> dfb <- as.data.frame(as.character(LETTERS[c(1:4,7:9,15:25)]))
> names(dfa) <- 'letter1'
> names(dfb) <- 'letter2'
> dfa
   letter1
1        C
2        D
3        E
4        F
5        G
6        H
7        I
8        J
9        K
10       L
11       M
12       N
> dfb
   letter2
1        A
2        B
3        C
4        D
5        G
6        H
7        I
8        O
9        P
10       Q
11       R
12       S
13       T
14       U
15       V
16       W
17       X
18       Y
```

and I want to obtain this:

```
   letter1   letter2
1     <NA>         A
2     <NA>         B
3        C         C
4        D         D
5        E      <NA>
6        F      <NA>
7        G         G
8        H         H
9        I         I
10       J      <NA>
11       K      <NA>
12       L      <NA>
13       M      <NA>
14       N      <NA>
15    <NA>         O
16    <NA>         P
17    <NA>         Q
18    <NA>         R
19    <NA>         S
20    <NA>         T
21    <NA>         U
22    <NA>         V
23    <NA>         W
24    <NA>         X
25    <NA>         Y
```

For that purpose, I used the following command, but the output does not make much sense to me:

```
> merge(dfa, dfb, by.x='letter1', by.y='letter2', all=TRUE)
   letter1
1        C
2        D
3        E
4        F
5        G
6        H
7        I
8        J
9        K
10       L
11       M
12       N
13       A
14       B
15       O
16       P
17       Q
18       R
19       S
20       T
21       U
22       V
23       W
24       X
25       Y
```

Thinking the problem might be due to the fact that the `data.frames` are one column each, I tried again making a dummy column, but still the output is nowhere near what I expected...

```
> dfa <- data.frame(NUM=1:12, letter1=as.character(LETTERS[3:14]))
> dfb <- data.frame(NUM=1:18, letter2=as.character(LETTERS[c(1:4,7:9,15:25)]))
> merge(dfa, dfb, by.x='letter1', by.y='letter2', all=TRUE)
   letter1 NUM.x NUM.y
1        C     1     3
2        D     2     4
3        E     3    NA
4        F     4    NA
5        G     5     5
6        H     6     6
7        I     7     7
8        J     8    NA
9        K     9    NA
10       L    10    NA
11       M    11    NA
12       N    12    NA
13       A    NA     1
14       B    NA     2
15       O    NA     8
16       P    NA     9
17       Q    NA    10
18       R    NA    11
19       S    NA    12
20       T    NA    13
21       U    NA    14
22       V    NA    15
23       W    NA    16
24       X    NA    17
25       Y    NA    18
```

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify columns in `by` they would be merged into one by `merge`. In your attempt you add a new column sequentially which gives incorrect output, we instead need to `match` them against one common value (here using `LETTERS`).

```
dfa$inds <- match(dfa$letter1, LETTERS)
dfb$inds <- match(dfb$letter2, LETTERS)

merge(dfa, dfb, all = TRUE)

#   inds letter1 letter2
#1     1    <NA>       A
#2     2    <NA>       B
#3     3       C       C
#4     4       D       D
#5     5       E    <NA>
#6     6       F    <NA>
#7     7       G       G
#8     8       H       H
#9     9       I       I
#10   10       J    <NA>
#11   11       K    <NA>
#12   12       L    <NA>
#13   13       M    <NA>
#14   14       N    <NA>
#15   15    <NA>       O
#16   16    <NA>       P
#17   17    <NA>       Q
#18   18    <NA>       R
#19   19    <NA>       S
#20   20    <NA>       T
#21   21    <NA>       U
#22   22    <NA>       V
#23   23    <NA>       W
#24   24    <NA>       X
#25   25    <NA>       Y
```

As a general case, we can get the common value by combining all the values both the columns can take (`all_vals`) and then `match` with these values.

```
all_vals <- unique(c(dfa$letter1, dfb$letter2))
dfa$inds <- match(dfa$letter1, all_vals)
dfb$inds <- match(dfb$letter2, all_vals)
merge(dfa, dfb, all = TRUE, by = "inds")
```

---

For multiple such dataframes it is better to put them together in list, assuming the first column is the one we want to match across all the dataframes

```
list_df <- list(dfa, dfb, dfc)
all_vals <- Reduce(union, lapply(list_df, `[[`, 1))
list_df <- lapply(list_df, function(x) {x$inds <- match(x[[1]], all_vals) ; x})
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE), list(dfa, dfb, dfc))
```

**data**

```
dfa <- data.frame(letter1 = LETTERS[3:14], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfb <- data.frame(letter2 = LETTERS[c(1:4,7:9,15:25)], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dfc <- data.frame(letter3 = LETTERS[1:4], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes I was just thinking of that... that works for the MWE, but in my real world case I do not know all the possible cases that can appear (the same way as we know which `LETTERS`)... think about it as possible people names instead of letters...

Comment: @DaniCee ok..I updated the answer which would work in general cases.

Comment: Thanks! But I am still struggling... The new problem arises when I want to add yet another `data.frame` of the same form (say `dfc`) to the final merged `data.frame` (say `final.df`). Could you extend your answer to reflect this? I cannot wrap my head around it... Thanks!

Comment: @DaniCee okay...I have added an update to the answer. You can check it.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I add one at a time iteratively inside a loop... so the starting point is the merged `final.df` and every time a new `dfx` with the same format as the original `data.frames`, to make `final.df` bigger one column at a time... is that possible?

Comment: are you doing something else in the `for` loop apart from merging? because the above approach does the same using `Reduce` without explicitly using a `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah I do a lot of things... Essentially it's a program that reads in one file at a time, extracts some parameters, and compares those to the ones in the other files to see discrepancies... so it can be 10 or 100 input files, I just want to keep adding columns to `final.df` merging in this way, to see which files have discrepancies in their parameters... and in principle I want all files reflected, one column for each

Comment: the issue might arise when you have values in `dfc` which are not present in `final.df`, hence you need to use the `Reduce` approach. Instead of merging them  sequentially one after another, read all the files first, put them in a list using `mget` or manually and then you can continue as updated in the answer.

Comment: Yeah I guess essentially I just need 2 loops, one to read in all the files and record all possible values, and the second loop to merge as in the first answer